# FTP AS400 WRITE IN A FILE

Tags: php, ftp, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to write to an existing file in an as400 ftp server in append mode ... but it keeps giving me error ... the error it returns is that it gives "operation completed etc ..." but does not write anything to the file... what am I wrong?

```
// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");

// try to login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    echo "Connected as $ftp_user@$ftp_server\n";
} else {
    echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user\n";
}

// execute command
if (ftp_raw($conn_id, "cd /QSYS.LIB/DWFOR800.LIB")) {
    debug("cd /QSYS.LIB/DWFOR800.LIB executed successfully");
} else {
    debug("could not execute cd /QSYS.LIB/DWFOR800.LIB");
}

// open file for reading
$file = CODE_PHP_PATH."test.txt";

// execute command
if (ftp_raw($conn_id, "app $file EDI50FTP.FILE")) {
    debug("app $file EDI50FTP.FILE executed successfully");
} else {
    debug("could not execute app $file EDI50FTP.FILE");
}

// close this connection and file handler
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Comment: Don't suppress errors: `@ftp_login` and please don't let us guess the error message.

Comment: Also the command's are uppercase and I assume it's not `app` but `APPEND`.

Comment: [`ftp_raw()`](https://www.php.net/ftp_raw) doesn't return a boolean value but an array of strings from the server. They can be positive or negative messages, your `if` is not working this way.

Comment: Hi Daniel,
the error it returns is that it gives "operation completed etc ..." but does not write anything to the file

Comment: why are you trying to do this with `ftp_raw` instead of `ftp_append`

Comment: HI @jmarkmurphy, because i am using php 5.6.4

Comment: which statement gives the error? What is the error?

Comment: What is the format of EDI50FTP.FILE?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe depends on the version of IBM i? It could be that you are on an old version. You used to have to include:

```
quote site namefmt 1
```

as the first command. So that it recognizes the naming used. It defaults to the library file system, but, at IBM i V7.2 and later at least, it will default to the integrated file system if your first command is `cd`.

This is my ftp log for Windows Console FTP, and it works for me.

```
230 MMURPHY logged on.
ftp> cd /QSYS.LIB/JMMTEST.LIB
250-NAMEFMT set to 1.
250 "/QSYS.LIB/JMMTEST.LIB" is current library.
ftp> append test.txt TEST.FILE
200 PORT subcommand request successful.
150 Sending file to member TEST in file TEST in library JMMTEST.
226 File transfer completed successfully.
ftp: 934 bytes sent in 0.21Seconds 4.36Kbytes/sec.
```

So it looks like your ftp commands are correct if you are using IBM i v7.2 or greater. Given that you are using PHP 5.6. It is possible that you are also using an outdated version of IBM i.

An other possibility is the file you are appending to is not a physical file with a single character field. FTP doesn't really transfer database files, but it does transfer stream files. A database file can be done, but I'm not sure it can be appended, and you typically have to use binary mode to do it.